# Unmarshal JSON with an array

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I am trying to Unmarshal the following JSON object which is generated by couchDB and returns for a cURL request in Go, the cURL request code is not mentioned here as it is out of scope of this question and I have assigned it to the variable called `mail` in the code section.

the JSON data structure:

```
{
"total_rows": 4,
"offset": 0,
"rows": [{
              "id": "36587e5d091a0d49f739c25c0b000c05",
              "key": "36587e5d091a0d49f739c25c0b000c05",
              "value": {
                          "rev": "1-92471472a3de492b8657d3103f5f6e0d"
                       }
        }]
}
```

and here is my code to unmarshel the above JSON object,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Couchdb struct {
    TotalRows int `json:"total_rows"`
    Offset    int `json:"offset"`
    Rows      []struct {
        ID    string `json:"id"`
        Key   string `json:"key"`
        Value struct {
             Rev string `json:"rev"`
        } `json:"value"`
    } `json:"rows"`
}

func main() {
     mail := []byte(`{"total_rows":4,"offset":0,"rows":[{"id":"36587e5d091a0d49f739c25c0b000c05","key":"36587e5d091a0d49f739c25c0b000c05","value":{"rev":"1-92471472a3de492b8657d3103f5f6e0d"}}]}`)

     var s Couchdb
     err := json.Unmarshal(mail, &s)
     if err != nil {
         panic(err)
     }


     //fmt.Printf("%v", s.TotalRows)
     fmt.Printf("%v", s.Rows)
}
```

and the above code is working fine and you can access the working code here [with this link](https://play.golang.org/p/fwU6jQiTn-x) in the Go Play Ground.

I need to get the `36587e5d091a0d49f739c25c0b000c05` value which is the `id` of `rows` so I am trying to do it like this

`fmt.Printf("%v", s.Rows.ID)`

and it returns this error
`prog.go:33:25: s.Rows.ID undefined (type []struct { ID string "json:\"id\""; Key string "json:\"key\""; Value struct { Rev string "json:\"rev\"" } "json:\"value\"" } has no field or method ID)`

but it works for `fmt.Printf("%v", s.Rows)` and it returns

`[{36587e5d091a0d49f739c25c0b000c05 36587e5d091a0d49f739c25c0b000c05 {1-92471472a3de492b8657d3103f5f6e0d}}]`

My ultimate goal is to get `36587e5d091a0d49f739c25c0b000c05` and assign it to GO variable but stuck getting that value using GO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call :

```
fmt.Println(s.Rows[0].ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

You define  `Rows` as slice of struct that means you should iterate Rows with [for](https://gobyexample.com/range) for execution of values.

```
for _, item := range s.Rows {
        fmt.Println(item.ID)
}
```